# Setting color of itemize body

Tags: beamer

What is wrong with the following declaration.

```
\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}}
```

I want to set the color of itemize body to that of beamer's frametitle.

**Update**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=blue}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item A
  \item B
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to use beamer's frametitle color for itemize body i.e. colorize A and B.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: @HarishKumar An example is provided.

Comment: Try with `\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=structure}` BTW which color theme are you using?

Comment: @HarishKumar I am using the default color theme.

Comment: @HarishKumar. Yes. Its working. Thanks. Please post an answer so that I may accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the colors in beamer use a base called `structure`. So you can use

```
 \setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=structure}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{albatross}   %% just for example
\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=structure}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Fame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item A
  \item B
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "copy" the beamer color `frametitle` you can use the following command:

```
\setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{parent=frametitle}
```

In this way both the `fg` and `bg` parts of the color are set even if, depending on the template, the `bg` part might not be used.